Having multiple issues when attempting to convert h.264 files to h.265 using HEVC
I am using RiaanAspeling's script for the conversion of my library that I currently have, most of it is H264 and I want to convert it to H265 to reduce the size of the files that I have hosted on my NAS.
I have used ChatGPT, because I have no idea about programming. I managed to test and I got the following. The test file has a weight of 1.13GB.
In the first script it completed the conversion using my Intel 8700K CPU and the new file had a weight of 320MB, very good! But it takes a long time.
In the second script I got the conversion to use my Nvidia RTX 3080 and the newly generated file had a weight of 1.15GB, wot? But it took about a third of the time it took in the first script.
Also in both cases the script removed the second audio track and only 1 subtitle track.
What am I doing wrong? I want to use the RTX 3080 to convert, otherwise it will take too long. Also I want to keep the audio and subtitle tracks that the original video has.

CPU: https://ibb.co/6bf7XN7
GPU: https://ibb.co/ZSZNmyp
Original: https://ibb.co/3fRBY7z

bash compress_video3.sh -e mkv -s "D:/Temp/Convert_H265/H264/Into the Night (2020)/T1" -d "D:/Temp/Convert_H265/H265" -f 1

Code is here:
#!/bin/bash

#=============================================================================
#
#    FILE: compress_video.sh
#
#    USAGE:
#       compress_video.sh [-e EXTENSION] [-s SOURCE] [-d DESTINATION] [-f 0]
#                          -e EXTENSION      Specify the file extension
#                                            to filter on source. Eg: -e mkv'
#                          -s SOURCE         Specify the source folder
#                                            to compress from. Eg: /mnt/myvideos'
#                          -d DESTINATION    Specify the destination folder to
#                                            compress to. Note that files will
#                                            not be overwritten. Eg: /mnt/converted'
#
#    DESCRIPTION: This script compresses videos to h265 (HEVC) from one location
#    to another recursively without overwriting the destination.
#
#    Copyright 2022 Riaan Aspeling
#
#    Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a
#    copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software")
#    , to deal in the Software without restriction, including without
#    limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute,
#    sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to
#    whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
#    conditions:
#
#    The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included
#    in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
#    THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS
#    OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
#    MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
#    IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
#    CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
#    TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
#    SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
#
#       OPTIONS: ---
#  REQUIREMENTS: ---
#          BUGS: Report bugs to Riaan Aspeling via Github:
#                https://github.com/RiaanAspeling/CompressVideo/issues
#         NOTES: ---
#        AUTHOR: Riaan Aspeling
#  CONTRIBUTORS: ---
#  ORGANIZATION: UNAD cc
#       CREATED: 2022-07
#  LAST UPDATED: 2023-01
#       VERSION: 1
#     SCRIPT ID: 1
#=============================================================================

# show the usage pattern of this script
function usage()
{
    echo "Usage: $(basename $0) [-e EXTENSION] [-s SOURCE] [-d DESTINATION] [-f 0]" 2>&1
    echo '    -e EXTENSION      Specify the file extension to filter on source. Eg: -e mkv'
    echo '    -s SOURCE         Specify the source folder to compress from. Eg: /mnt/myvideos'
    echo '    -d DESTINATION    Specify the destination folder to compress to. Note that files will not be overwritten. Eg: /home/user/myvideos'
    echo '    -f 0/1            0=None (default), 1=Report the frame count before each encoding'
    exit 1
}

# unset variables
unset -v extension
unset -v source
unset -v destination
unset -v showframes

# if no input argument found, exit the script with usage
if [[ ${#} -eq 0 ]]; then
    usage
fi

# draw a dashed line the width of the console
function draw_line()
{
    local width=$(tput cols)
    for (( x = 0; x < "$width"; ++x )); do echo -e -n "\e[1;32m-"; done
    echo -e "\e[0m"
}

# list of arguments expected in the input
optstring=":e:s:d:f:"

showframes=0

# assign arguments to variables
while getopts ${optstring} arg; do
  case "${arg}" in
    e)
        extension=${OPTARG}
        ;;
    s)
        source=$OPTARG
        ;;
    d)
        destination=$OPTARG
        ;;
    f)
        showframes=$OPTARG
        ;;
    :)
        echo "$0: Must supply an argument to -$OPTARG." >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    ?)
        echo "Invalid option: -${OPTARG}."
        exit 2
        ;;
  esac
done

# check that all arguments was supplied
if [ -z "$extension" ]; then
    echo "Extension argument is required!"
    usage
fi
if [ -z "$source" ]; then
    echo "Source argument is required!"
    usage
fi
if [ -z "$destination" ]; then
    echo "Destination argument is required!"
    usage
fi

# Enable globstar for recursive matching
shopt -s globstar

# Loop though all sub-folders and files from the source folder.
for i in "$source"/**/*."$extension"; do
    relative_path="${i#$source}"

    # Check if the destination file already exists.
    if [[ -f "$destination$relative_path" ]]; then
        echo -e "\e[1;33mDestination file exists: $destination$relative_path"
        continue
    fi

    # Extract the codex used in the source file
    codex=$(ffprobe -hide_banner -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$i")

    # Check if the source file is already compressed with h265. (No need to re-compress)
    if [ "${codex//$'\r'/}" = "hevc" ]; then
        echo -e "\e[1;33mSource file is already HEVC encoded : $i"
        continue
    fi

    # Extract the video dimensions from the source file
    width=$(ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$i")
    height=$(ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$i")

    draw_line
    if [ showframes = "0" ]; then
        echo -e "Compressing \e[1;32m""$i""\e[0m with size (\e[1;31m" $width "x" $height "\e[0m) to file \e[1;34m""$destination""""$relative_path""\e[0m"
    else
        frames=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_packets -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -of csv=p=0 "$i")
        echo -e "Compressing \e[1;32m""$i""\e[0m with size \e[1;31m" $width "x" $height "\e[0m and with \e[1;31m" $frames "\e[0m frames to file \e[1;34m""$destination""""$relative_path""\e[0m"
    fi
    draw_line

    # Create the output folder if it doesn't exist
    mkdir -p "$destination""$(dirname "$relative_path")"

    # Run ffmpeg with nice to not hog all CPU for itself
    nice ffmpeg -stats -hide_banner -loglevel error -hwaccel cuvid -i "$i" -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset slow -rc vbr_hq -cq 23 -c:a copy "$destination/$relative_path"
done

Any help would be welcome.

The encoder in your GPU is designed to be fast, not particularly efficient or high quality. It might be able to be tuned, but CPU encoding will almost certainly have better quality at lower bitrates.

This ^^^ It doesn't matter (much) the script/software tool, what matters is the codecs involved and the encoder used, as brilliantly summarized above. For the other problem you don't need to reinvent the wheel. GUI software exists - Handbrake - that let's you manage audio and subtitles tracks (even adding external .srt) easily. Performance will be exactly the same and will be determined by the preset used. Except those explicitly mentioning "NV" - use Nvidia, quicker, larger file and worse quality - all the other use CPU so slower but smaller file and best quality.
